# Automated Emails - custom, based on member

Tags: add-on, email

Is there a way to send emails based on member group (e.g. when a member registers and is assigned group x, they get email x; if group y, they get email y)? My site also is multi-lingual, so being able to send email based on the site's current language when user signs up would be nice. Or being able to send email based on user's language preference would also be good (I'm using SafeCracker registration, so my members have an associated channel entry which can store a language preference).

Possible to do in EE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [**Postmaster addon**](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster). If any addon can do what you're wanting it will be this one. It also has [**hooks**](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks) for custom development if you end up going that way.